# Change subnet for Bridge network of GitLab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab Pipeline based on the `python:3.10.11` image. The runner needs access to a local network that is on 172.17.0.0 via SSH/Paramiko. But it is unable to connect to the newtwork, when the runner pings an IP on the local network, it says `Destination Host Unreachable`. I imagine this is because the default Docker subnet is also 172.17.0.0. Is it possible to change the default Docker Bridge IP for a GitLab runner? Perhaps in the `config.toml` file?

Comment: Configuring different ip range for containers may help: https://serverfault.com/a/936255/487753

Or try host network mode: https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/